# Add image to existing MySql record

Tags: php, mysql

I'm quite new to PHP and MYSQL.

I need to add an image to an existing record.

So I have a list of records and when I click the link directing to this page.

In this form I would like to ad an image.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid it looks like your question is too overly broad to really be a proper question for this site. Please include the steps you have taken so far and the specific problem that you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

**I would highly discourge you from saving files in a database like that.**

Here are the steps that I have used before:

1. I would create a folder on the server for each user.
2. Save the filename and extension in a table.
3. Save the file to the server folder.

If I wanted to grab a file I would go to the right directory and file name.

**Examples:**

Profile Picture = {userFiles/userID/filename}

Contract for Billy = {userFiles/{Billy'sID}/{filename}

Comment: Storing big files and/or images outside the database (in a folder for example) can work pretty well. The big down side is that saving the image does not participate in the transaction, and the data could become inconsistent in time. If transactionality is not important for your application, then there's nothing wrong with this solution.